# Running selenium from Visual Studio Code terminal with virtualenv

Tags: selenium, visual-studio-code, selenium-chromedriver, virtualenv, geckodriver

I've been trying for over 2 hours to run my scraper from the Visual Studio Terminal. At first i thought the problem was that my chromedriver/geckodriver were not owned by the correct user/didn't have proper rw rights so i checked this. Also my virtualenv is owned by the user and has appropriate rights. 
When i run the script from the console it works (this means first activating the `virtualenv` and then running the script as user. So it's not a chromedriver problem(not even a path problem). 
It doesn't work when i try running it from the Visual Studio Code terminal, and i keep getting:

This error for `chromedriver`:

```
    paras = self.driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//p")
  File "/home/mike/Documents/Envs/Scrapers/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 1007, in find_elements
    'value': value})['value'] or []
  File "/home/mike/Documents/Envs/Scrapers/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/mike/Documents/Envs/Scrapers/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable
  (Session info: chrome=77.0.3865.120)
```

And this error for `firefox`:

```
    return webdriver.Firefox()
  File "/home/mike/Documents/Envs/Scrapers/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 174, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "/home/mike/Documents/Envs/Scrapers/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/mike/Documents/Envs/Scrapers/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/home/mike/Documents/Envs/Scrapers/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/mike/Documents/Envs/Scrapers/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: invalid argument: can't kill an exited process
```

I have provided the appropiate path for `python` in the `settings.json` file of my project, as such:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "/home/mike/Documents/Envs/Scrapers/bin/python3"
}
```

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem? I have the same issue with Firefox / VSCode / geckodriver / Linux. It only works in VSCode in headless mode.

Comment: I opened a bug with Microsoft: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/88390

Comment: @DjAlan sorry for the late reply, no, i haven't. I quit using Selenium and went for Puppeteer, it's much faster for my use cases and it can run headless.

Answer (score 1):

Try to ran it headless, if it worked so the problem with opening new display.

Paste the following in the VS Code terminal and try again

```
export DISPLAY=":0"
```